# Jenkins dotnet test

Tags: .net, jenkins, curl

If the unit testing fails, the pipeline ends.  I want to send the unit test results regardless of failure or success.  I am using an "Execute Shell" build trigger. (and want to)

```sh
/dotnet/dotnet test --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=UnitTests.xml" /pathtotest

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJob/UnitTests.xml https://myendpoint.com
```

If the unit test fails, the curl command will not run because the pipeline ends with a failure.  If the unit test succeeds, the curl command WILL run.  It want it run regardless.

How do I do that?

Comment: How about adding a [post action](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) and writing the curl command in the **always** condition?

Comment: By defaut Jenkins does not have the option to execute additional shell commands in a post action.  (I am using execute shell, not groovy pipeline) I did find a plugin that allows you execute additional commands in a post pipeline action, and that worked.  Thanks!


I am still curious if the same can be accomplished without the plugin - almost like a try catch linux cmd?  Dunno if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

We use the ".Net SDK Support" plugin. It is much cleaner than writing shell scripts that have to run on windows and linux nodes.

With it you just set `continueOnError:true` and `unstableIfErrors:true`. This allows the build to continue but marks it 'yellow' (unstable) instead of red when tests fail.

Example:

```
 echo("Running tests in '${buildSolutionFile}' calling 'dotnet test' ...")
 dotnetTest( configuration: my_configuration_map, noBuild: true, project: buildSolutionFile, continueOnError: true, unstableIfErrors: true, properties:[:], logger:"trx;LogFileName=UnitTestFile.trx", filter: dotnetTestFilter, sdk: sdkVersion)
```

Here's the reference document: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/dotnet-sdk/#dotnettest-net-run-unit-tests-test

But if you need to do it the brute force way via shell commands and build status manipulation, try something like this:

**Linux**

```
try {
   def testtool='dotnet'
   sh """${testtool}\" test --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=UnitTests.xml" /pathtotest"""
} catch (error) {
   currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
   errorDetails = 
"""Unit tests failure! 
Suggestions:
1. verify that tests .csproj file target framework 'net6.0' or better
2. verify that the tests are running
Error: ${error}"""
   echo(errorDetails)
}
//push test result to my api if they exist
if (fileExists('/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJob/UnitTests.xml')){
 sh """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJob/UnitTests.xml"""
}
```

**Windows**

```
try {
   def testtool='/dotnet/dotnet'
   echo("Running tests in '${buildSolutionFile}' calling test target...")
   bat """cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & \"${testtool}\" test --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=UnitTests.xml" /pathtotest" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%""".replaceAll("[\n\r\t]", " ")
} catch (error) {
   currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
   errorDetails = 
"""Unit tests failure! 
Suggestions:
1. verify that tests .csproj file target framework 'net6.0' or better
2. verify that the tests are running
Error: ${error}"""
   echo(errorDetails)
}
//push test result to my api if they exist
if (fileExists('/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJob/UnitTests.xml')){
 bat """cmd.exe /C " chcp 1252 & curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyJob/UnitTests.xml https://myendpoint.com" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%""".replaceAll("[\n\r\t]", " ")
}
```